# Editing a single attribute with more than one form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, has-many-through

**Background:** Users and communities share a

> has_many :through

relationship. Each community has a "community_type" string that identifies it (ie "Gender", "City", etc.).

**Objective:** In my edit form, I'd like to allow the user to edit his :community_ids based on community type. Something like:

> ```
> <%= form_for current_user do |f| %>
> <%= f.collection_select(:community_ids, Community.filtered_by("Gender"), :id, :name) %>
> <%= f.collection_select(:community_ids, Community.filtered_by("City"), :id, :name) %>
> <% end %>
> ```

The issue is that the form only accepts the last form field value for :community_ids - in this case being the "City" - rather than merging all of them as one big :community_ids array.

**Solution:**

For those interested, I ended up refactoring my model code from the answers below to this:

```
  %W[ community1 community2 community3 community4 ].each do |name|
    define_method "#{name}" do
      self.communities.filtered_by("#{name}").map(&:name)
    end
    define_method "#{name}_ids" do
      self.communities.filtered_by("#{name}").map(&:id)
    end
    define_method "#{name}_ids=" do |val|
      self.community_ids += val
    end
  end
```

Comment: One question: do you just want to pick one of each type for your user, or can a user have several of each type (I'm just trying to figure our if `select_tag`s are the best way to go)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you're using select boxes for a `has_many` relationship? It seems checkboxes would be more appropriate. If you want to go with select boxes, I don't think you can use `FormHelper#select`, because as far as I know, it's expecting a single value, and your `community_ids` is an array. This is why it's only picking one of the values you give it.

For a select box (or any field), you can combine the values across fields by adding `[]` to the parameter name which tells Rails that the parameter is an array of values. You can do this by using regular `select_tag` to create the fields, and setting the parameter name as follows:

```rb
<%= form_for current_user do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag("user[community_ids][]", options_for_select(Community.filtered_by("Gender").map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, :selected => current_user.communities.filtered_by("Gender").first.id) %>
  <%= select_tag("user[community_ids][]", options_for_select(Community.filtered_by("City").map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, :selected => current_user.communities.filtered_by("City").first.id) %>
<% end %>
```

You could also go with Ryan's approach of sending separate parameters, though one downside is your `User` model will have to be very aware of the types of communities that exist, and you'll have to write separate logic in the `User` model for each type of community. This will make your resources less modular. But if you do go that way, I'd suggest using pseudo-attributes instead of a `before_save` so that your `community_ids` get updated automatically from the `params`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def community_gender_ids=(cg_ids)
    self.community_ids ||= []
    self.community_ids += cg_ids
  end

  def community_city_ids=(cc_ids)
    self.community_ids ||= []
    self.community_ids += cc_ids
  end
  ...
end
```

And then your `select_tag` calls would look something like this:

```
<%= form_for current_user do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag("user[community_gender_ids][]", options_for_select(Community.filtered_by("Gender").map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, :selected => current_user.communities.filtered_by("Gender").first.id) %>
  <%= select_tag("user[community_city_ids][]", options_for_select(Community.filtered_by("City").map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, :selected => current_user.communities.filtered_by("City").first.id) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: interesting. I'm playing around with this approach but keep getting an "undefined method `community_gender_ids' for #<User>" error. i put these methods in user.rb and @Ryan's form view. Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer for an expansion on tsherif's answer. Basically the problem is that the form_for helper is trying to pre-populate the select field for which values should be selected. It is trying to call current_user.community_gender_ids. Because there are no "getter" methods, it says method undefined. I added some getter methods to my answer for you.

Comment: @neon I made some substantial edits to my answer that I think should make things clearer, and suggest some other approaches. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: trying this out now, but to answer your question - users can have multiple of certain community_types and only one of others (like Gender)

Answer (score 1):

Updated to complete tsherif's (better than my original) answer.

view.rb

```
<%= form_for current_user do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:community_gender_ids, Community.filtered_by("Gender"), :id, :name, {}, id: 'community-gender-options') %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:community_city_ids, Community.filtered_by("City"), :id, :name, {}, id: 'community-city-options') %>
<% end %>
```

model.rb

```
def community_gender_ids=(cg_ids)
  self.community_ids ||= []
  self.community_ids += cg_ids
end

def community_city_ids=(cc_ids)
  self.community_ids ||= []
  self.community_ids += cc_ids
end

def community_gender_ids
  self.communities.select(:id).where(:community_type => 'gender').map(&:id)
end

def community_city_ids
  self.communities.select(:id).where(:community_type => 'city').map(&:id)
end
```

Alternatively, you could write some CoffeeScript/Javascript to bind to the select tags and add the IDs to a hidden value which is then submitted to the server with the form.